# How to draw spectrogram for multiple input signals in Matlab

Tags: matlab, signals, spectrogram

I have 64 different input signals (features) each represented by a vector of a same length. I am using Matlab and would like to make a spectrogram of all of them like shown below. From what I have seen, many tutorials and examples on the internet are of making spectrogram from 1 vector and not multiple.

[image: spectrogram]

Comment: Do you want to create a matrix from your 64 vectors?

Comment: I realised I wasn't searching for the right method. Turns out Matlab heatmap is the correct approach for anyone with similar question.